# Python запись строк Excel в множество txt файлов

Tags: python, pandas, excel, xlsx

Всем привет, подскажите как реализовать, чтобы **1 строка Excel равнялась 1 txt файлу**, у меня никак не получается это реализвать. К примеру: 1 строчка эксель файла записывалась в один txt файл построчно, и так далее. Вот пример моего кода. У меня в один txt файл записывается вся таблица эксель

```
excel_data = pd.read_excel('religi.xlsx', usecols="B,C,E,D")
#print(excel_data)
df = excel_data
dfAsString = df.to_string(header=False, index=False)
print(dfAsString)


for i in dfAsString:
    f = open('/home/vk/datatxt/'+str(i)+'.txt', 'w')
    f.write(dfAsString)
    f.close()
```

Comment: _'в один txt файл записывается вся таблица эксель'_ все правильно, вы же делаете `f.write(dfAsString)`

Comment: @SergFSM Спасибо за ответ! Да, я понимаю, но как сделать так, чтобы каждая строчка эксель заносилась по-отдельности в .txt файлы. Допустим: у меня 400 строк, соответственно 400 файлов .txt и каждый файл содержит по строке соответственно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот немного поправил ваш код, попробуйте заменить цикл на этот (не тестировалось):

```
for i, r in enumerate(dfAsString.split('\n'), 1):
    f = open('/home/vk/datatxt/'+str(i)+'.txt', 'w')
    f.write(r)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!